# How to 'un' bold titles for MATLAB figures?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I'm trying to combine a few Matlab plots into one figure and therefore I'm wondering how I can create 'normal' tiles above my plots instead of the bold titles provided by Matlab. Below an example.

```
figure
plot((1:10).^2)
title({'First line';'Second line'})
```

Comment: I assume you want to remove the bold font? add  `'\bf your title'` as described here http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/title.html

Comment: Or are you trying to label a title for each of the plots you are combining? In which case you should use `subplot` and issue an individual title for each of your subplots.

Comment: @GameOfThrows shouldn't that be `\sl`?

Comment: @Dan Actually, I think `\rm` maybe the one he is looking for. I just remember \bf as bold font.

Comment: True that, apologies. \rm is indeed what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, `\rm` indeed, I was reading off the wrong line

Answer (score 8):

Make use of the `'FontWeight'` argument:

```
figure
plot((1:10).^2)
title({'First line';'Second line'},'FontWeight','Normal')
```

Note also that you can access the `'FontWeight'` argument for all text objects in your figure in one go---in case you have, e.g., several subplots in your figure---using `findall`:

```
myFig = figure;
subplot(2,1,1)
plot((1:10).^2)
title('First plot')
subplot(2,1,2)
plot((1:10).^2)
title('Second plot')

% Set 'Normal' font weight in both titles above
set(findall(myFig, 'Type', 'Text'),'FontWeight', 'Normal')
```

As stated in the comments above; for a single figure title, you can make use make use of `\rm` as an alternative. Note however that `\rm` depends on the (default) choice of `'Interpreter'` as `'tex'`, whereas the approach above is valid for all choices of interpreter (however with no effect for text objects using interpreter `'latex'`).